# Django-filters: BaseInFilter with a different separator

Tags: django, django-filter

I'm wanting to be able split text on a value other than a comma within django-filters.

I'm currently using django-filter along with a [BaseInFilter](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ref/filters.html?highlight=IntegerField#baseinfilter) to allow searching for multiple integer values in a model. This filter separates values based on a comma, and I can't seem to override the function that splits the values. It is likely that I'm misunderstanding where this split is happening.

I have tried to override this method in the class `BaseCSVWidget`

```
def value_from_datadict(self, data, files, name):
    value = super().value_from_datadict(data, files, name)
    if value is not None:
        if value == '':  # empty value should parse as an empty list
            return []
        return value.split(',')
    return None
```

by placing it in my filter with a different separator:

```
class PidnInFilter(BaseInFilter, NumberFilter):
    def value_from_datadict(self, data, files, name):
        value = super().value_from_datadict(data, files, name)

        if value is not None:
            if value == '':  # empty value should parse as an empty list
                return []
            return value.split(' ')
        return None
```

I've also tried creating my own widget class and overriding there:

```
from django_filters.widgets import BaseCSVWidget

class MyWidget(BaseCSVWidget):
    def value_from_datadict(self, data, files, name):
        print('value_from_datadict reached')
        print(data)
        value = super().value_from_datadict(data, files, name)
        print(value)

        if value is not None:
            if value == '':  # empty value should parse as an empty list
                return []
            return value.split(' ')
        return None


class PidnInFilter(BaseInFilter, NumberFilter):
    base_widget_class = MyWidget
```

Both fail to split on whitespace. Optimally, I'd like to use `\n` as the separator, or be able to choose a separator based on context. But, I'm missing something obvious in where this happens...

Comment: Space is rarely used as a separator in "CSV". CSV's counterpart TSV splits by tabs, aka `\t`. Maybe your input uses tabs?

Comment: Well, it's that I'd like to be able to specify the separator. The widget is there for users to type in or copy/paste values to then filter on. If a user has a bunch of values in Excel that they want to copy/paste into the widget and filter on, the separator is `\n`. But, in other contexts, it might be something else

Comment: I know, what I'm saying is that maybe you're testing with tabs instead of spaces, so that's why the split seems to not work.

Comment: Thanks for responding, but I've double checked that it is not tabs. I've tried different separators with manually typing in different variables. All with no luck

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the classes are composed, not inherited: you're trying to set the widget on the filter, but the filter defines a field and the field defines the widget:

```
MyFilter
    base_field_class = MyField

    MyField
        base_widget_class = MyWidget
```

So setting `base_widget_class` on MyFilter does nothing. This should get you in the right direction (untested):

```py
from django_filters.fields import BaseCSVField
from django_filters.widgets import BaseCSVWidget
from django_filters.filters import BaseInFilter, NumberFilter


class PidWidget(BaseCSVWidget):
    separator = " "

    def value_from_datadict(self, data, files, name):
        value = super().value_from_datadict(data, files, name)

        if value is not None:
            if value == "":  # empty value should parse as an empty list
                return []
            return value.split(self.separator)
        return None


class PidField(BaseCSVField):
    base_widget_class = PidWidget


class PidFilter(BaseInFilter, NumberFilter):
    base_field_class = PidField
```